# Enemy awareness for Tower Defense

Tags: tower-defense, dynamic-difficulty

1I have a thesis project about dynamic difficulty in games and I'm focusing on Tower Defense genre. My plan let the enemy units or each units in a wave know that a tile on a path is dangerous (or many units have died there). When an enemy unit with a skill(for example area shield boost) pass or walks to a tile with the most units killed in that tile it will trigger the skill to prevent minimal damage to the wave. What algorithm would be suitable to achieve that?

PS: is this a good idea for a dynamic difficulty, if not suggestions are accepted.

Comment: If you store the number of units died per tile, then this is a trivial find maximum algorithm.

Comment: hmmm... seems that it's a little easy. What if I will use the tower range instead? with the most overlapping range will be counted as the danger zone.

Comment: What's wrong with being easy? Unless you want us to generate a thesis topic of sufficient difficulty, then it's offtopic for this site.

Comment: If you produce a thesis about dynamic difficulty in games, you should be the one doing the research and teaching us stuff about it, no?

Comment: What you suggest of doing is not dynamic difficulty, it's just an AI trait.

Comment: "Dynamic difficulty" usually means that the game analyzes how well the player is doing and then adjust the difficulty accordingly. In a run-off-the-mill tower defense game, you could, for example, look at how far units advance on average before getting killed and increase wave size whenever that point moves close to the spawn location.